# Bots preventing Meteor server from deploying on Digital Ocean with Meteor Up

Tags: security, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

When I am using Meteor Up to deploy my app to a Digital Ocean Droplet, I am receiving the following error in the logs preventing the app from deploying. I have the exact same deployment on a different Droplet with no such issue. According to my research online, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1212) caused by bots trying to make a GET request on the server, apparently attempting to use the server as a proxy.

EDIT: To clarify, my app loads in the browser just fine due to a previous successful deploy. This issue occurs when I want to deploy updates to the existing app.

My questions are as follows:

1. How did the bots start acting on this specific Droplet, and not my
   other Droplet? I'd like to prevent them from doing so in the future.
2. Are they continuously issuing GET requests on the server? If not, I
   should be able to deploy when they are not attacking?
3. Are the actions on the bot harming my app and its data? If I do
   eventually deploy successfully, they'll still be attacking my
   server, right?
4. How do I fix the problem given it already exists on one of my
   Droplets? I have tried to edit my mup.json to use a different port,
   e.g. 108 instead of 80, but that doesn't help. No one else has solved the problem, according to my online research on GitHub, StackOverflow, etc.

   Error: url must be a relative URL: http://httpheader.net
       at _.extend.classify (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:103)
       at appUrl (packages/fast-render/lib/server/inject.js:94)
       at Object.RouteController [as handle] (packages/fast-render/lib/server/inject.js:108)
       at next (/opt/musichunt/app/programs/server/npm/webapp/main/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
       at Object.cookieParser [as handle] (/opt/musichunt/app/programs/server/npm/fast-render/main/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/cookieParser.js:65:5)
       at next (/opt/musichunt[107.170.235.251] /app/programs/server/npm/webapp/main/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
       at Object.Package [as handle] (packages/spiderable/spiderable.js:126)
       at next (/opt/musichunt/app/programs/server/npm/webapp/main/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
       at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:72)
       at packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:61

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't stop your app from starting. While it is an error and known bug, it only shows up in the logs & does not crash or stop your Meteor app.

Its a bit of a nuisance, these bots scan entire IP blocks for open proxies. They don't cause any harm besides the error in your logs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It may not crash or stop my app, but it certainly appears to be preventing it from deploying (at least with Meteor Up). Do you have any ideas or suggestions regarding that?

Comment: I also have seen those log messages, but it never prevented me from deploying with meteor-up. Did you try running mup in debug mode? `DEBUG=* mup deploy`

Comment: To confirm this answer's suggestions, in a separate terminal run `mup logs -f` while running `mup deploy` in the other terminal. We can see directly that the errors caused by the bots did not occur during deployment; they occurred previously while the app was running successfully. The root problem preventing deployment still remains unresolved, and a separate SO question has been created  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329103/mup-deploy-killed-on-do-droplet-but-no-errors-in-logs)

Answer (score 0):

As Akshat stated, these bots shouldn't be a problem. They dont hammer your server. Usually its ~50 of those proxy checks a day (What i have seen).

You could check what meteor-up is saying in debug-mode while deployment.
Instead of `mup deploy` do `DEBUG=* mup deploy`

Also you could try another ip, if that ip gets hammered too much. Shutdown your droplet, create a snapshot. Spin up a new droplet from the snapshot. Check if it has a new ip and just deploy 
to that new ip.

If you can deploy end everything works, destroy the old droplet to save money ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I agree that it's possible that the bot errors found in the logs is not the root cause of the deployment problem. I'd like to debug more like you suggest, but how do I use `DEBUG=* mup deploy`? It doesn't seem to be doing anything different.

Comment: Also, the deploy sometimes works and other times doesn't, which is why I am suspicious of the bots causing the problem.

Comment: `DEBUG=* mup deploy` should show you a lot more output while deploying. Your assumption that thos bots "prevent you" has no ground to stand on, so why are you even thinking that they might be responsable. Imagine you have a server with lots of traffic, maybe 1000 users online at any time, wouldn't that "prevent" you even more from deploying?

Comment: `mup` doesnt do anything else then logging into your server with ssh, and executing some commands. Killing processes, copying some stuff, extracting stuff, launching processes. It doesn.t even interact with meteor directly. It's a very intelligent set of bash-scripts that makes your life easier, no more no less. Maybe you should look somewhere else for a solution, then hammering your head on that proxy bots thing.