# mup deploy killed on DO droplet but no errors in logs :(

Tags: node.js, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

Even just redeploying a previously successfully deployed app doesn't work. I monitored `mup logs -f` on a separate terminal while deploying, but nothing ever showed up there. Looks like it doesn't even get to the actual deploy step. I have Node 0.10.31 and Meteor 1.0. Is anyone else having this problem or know how to tackle it?

```
~# mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------

Building Started: /root/TS
Bundling Error: code=137, error:
-------------------STDOUT-------------------

-------------------STDERR-------------------
bash: line 1: 26400 Killed                  meteor build --directory /tmp/2b45aa84-0ffc-4ece-9cf4-aca8500409c3
```

Actually, the only errors I get relate to bots, but according to my [previous posting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031100/bots-preventing-meteor-server-from-deploying-on-digital-ocean-with-meteor-up/27034027?noredirect=1#comment42684279_27034027) those errors do not occur during deployment and should not be a problem.

Comment: When I run `meteor update` on the DO droplet, it also got `killed`. Did DO install a new firewall or block something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that upgrading from a $5/mo, 500 MB droplet to a $10/mo, 1 GB droplet solved the problem. I previously addressed the memory problem with the $5 droplet using [memory swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216127/memory-issue-with-meteor-up-mup-on-digital-ocean), but that appears to have run out of mileage. Still, it would have been nice to have errors in the logs to point me in the right directions.

Comment: I was able to fix this by increasing the swap space to 1gb.